# How long after the use by date can I safely cook and consume chicken drumsticks?

Tags: chicken

I discovered that the use by date of the chicken that I bought recently was two days ago.

It is still sealed and looks fine. I have yet to conduct the sniff test as I'm unsure whether there is any point.

Is it generally still safe to cook with?

Comment: The trouble with any question like this is it depends on the pack's journey from the factory to store, from store to your home, to the fridge, & exactly how cold your fridge is. Too many variables.

Comment: No it is not. It has a reason that the text says "use by" instead of "best before". Poultry belongs together with fish and clams to the most risky foods and you can´t see or smell the most hazardous ways it can spoil, but be assured that botulism is an extremely unpleasant death.